# How to remove [ ] from a Collection in Java?

Tags: java

I have a collection arraylist in Java.

For example when I do:

test is the collection.

```
System.out.println(test.getTester());
```

Why do I get the result of:
[jamesbond]

I only want jamesbond but why do they give me the [ ] too?

Comment: Because the toString() method of the object returned by test.getTester() prints the object that way. You didn't post the relevant code, so it's hard to say, but it's probably a List or a Set. Post the relevant code.

Comment: The more interesting question is: why do you want to remove the brackets? If you want to print the list, you can iterate over it and print each item yourself instead of using the `toString()` function...

Comment: Note that test is not the collection. Collections don't have any getTester() method. Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, assuming that you have ArrayList of Strings as the collection (since it's printing [jamesbond]).

When you write `test.getTester()`, the java calls the toString() method on the collection and it'll print elements between `[` and `]` with separated by comma.

You can use iterator over the collection to print the individual elements.

```
    List<String> stringColl = Arrays.asList("jamesbond","danielocean");

    // Java 8 
    stringColl.forEach(stringElem -> System.out.println(stringElem));

    // Java 7 or below 
    for(String stringElem : stringColl){
        System.out.println(stringElem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let a String help you with that and use the replace method...

## Example:

```
// if your list doesnt contain any element with the chars [ or ]
String listNoBrackets = l.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
System.out.println(listNoBrackets);

// if your list contains at least 1 element with the chars [ or ]
String listWithBrackets = l.toString().substring(1, l.toString().length() - 1);
System.out.println(listWithBrackets);
```

Comment: But now, instead of `jamesbond`, an entry will read `J[ames] Bond`, and thus the `toString()` will print `[J[ames] Bond]`... What does your code do? ;)

Comment: then he must either validate the content or do one of the 2 options I already postet....

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the first and last character with substring method.

```
String foo = test.getTester().toString();
System.out.println(foo.substring(1, foo.length() - 1);
```

Note: If you try to print an array with more than one object, you will see that the brackets are always the first and last character, the elements themselves are sperated with commas.